# Swap Gradient bgs in to main div for editing

Tags: javascript

I have created a swatch generator to create,  save and edit swatches, and on to the last bit of the edit function. I have got the main (top of page) div id and the swatch gradient div id, but stuck as to how to swap the swatch back in to the main div for re-editing (ie change the gradient colors) Current code grabs the correct elements, but cant get the small swatch back in to the main div to edit. Code is below:

```
editSwatch() {
 document.querySelector('#bg-gradient > .bg-gradient').setAttribute("id", "gradient");
  let mainID = document.getElementById('bodybg');
  let smallID = document.getElementById('gradient');
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  let mainSRC = mainID.style.backgroundImage;
  let smallSRC = smallID.style.backgroundImage;
```

//Move small gradient in to large div, image attached of elements in console.[image: Console elements]?
      mainSRC = smallSRC;

Just need to fix this to finish project, wanting to get that swatch gradient in to the main div at top, "bodybg", any tips welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy `style.background` or `style.backgroundImage`:

```js
document.getElementById("copyGradient").addEventListener("click", () => {
  var bodyBG = document.getElementById("bodybg");
  var gradientDiv = document.querySelector("#bg-gradient > .bg-gradient");
  bodyBG.style.backgroundImage = gradientDiv.style.backgroundImage;
})
```

```html
<div id="bodybg" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(241, 27, 136), rgb(222, 26, 221))">Main BG</div>
<div id="bg-gradient">
<div class="bg-gradient" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(28, 85, 223), rgb(26, 222, 89))">Gradient</div>
</div>
<button id="copyGradient">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Yes that works, the first time but if I switch to  different swath and try it then its doesnt although it has the correct div ids etc, is there some thing Im missing to fix this, if else statement or something? Thanks.    editSwatch() {
 document.querySelector('#bg-gradient > .bg-gradient').setAttribute("id", "gradient");
 let mainDiv = document.getElementById('bodybg');
 let smallDiv = document.getElementById('gradient');
 mainDiv.style.backgroundImage = smallDiv.style.backgroundImage;
},

Comment: Changed to reflect your comment

Comment: OK that works great, have got it in to he main div s the swatch, and it changes colors when reset the values, only thing now left is to get it back in to the exact same spot when it is republished/save. Id guess use the same selector and amend the publish function a bit. Thanks